# IntelliJ crashing after installing Veracode Greenlight plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Hello Stackoverflow comunity. I'm currently using IntelliJ 2021.2 Community edition for Java development and need to run security scan on my code. I'm using Veracode Greenlight plugin for the same (version - 202102160526-RELEASE). I have Java 11 Corretto installed on my Mac.

However, on restart the IntelliJ keeps crashing with the below error -

[intelliJ crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzXZT.png)

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Delete the plug-in from the Plugins directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#plugins-directory.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder, thanks for commenting, I actually wanted to get the plugin working in IntelliJ.

Comment: Contact the plug-in vendor for solution/fix.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.